# Connecting higher density LPDDR3 SDRAM than the ATSAMA5D27C processor supports

Tags: ram, addressing, ddr, sbc

I'm designing a Single Board Computer for the first time. The board will have ATSAMA5D27C as its MPU with LPDDR3 SDRAM. The datasheet specifies that the maximum SDRAM it can support is of 4Gb (512 Mbyte). I found this part which is currently available in Mouser: MT52L256M32D1PF-107 WT:B. It is an 8Gb LPDDR3 SDRAM.

I am going to use a single SDRAM in a 32-bit configuration. I want to know how to connect the CA pins of SDRAM to MPU so that it can address half of the 8Gb the SDRAM has to offer.

In the Microchip application note (Implementation of external DRAM on SAMA5D2 Devices, Pg 8)
https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/Atmel-44044-32-bit-ARM-Implementation-of-SDRAM-on-SAMA5D2x-Devices_Application-Note.pdf

they have connected RAS, CAS, WE, A0-6 of MPU to CA0-9 on SDRAM. Is it a standard to connect like this or is it because of the memory controller implementation of this MPU? And in my case should I connect it in the same way for it to use the lower half of SDRAM?

My understanding is: by looking at the truth table of the SDRAM, the row and column address, along with their bank address are latched in separate cycles. The available bit width of CA and RA is more than what is necessary for each bank. So it should be fine to connect in the same way as the LPDDR2 memory is connected in the application note, as the memory controller of the MPU will not be able to access the other part of SDRAM outside its address space anyway.

Is my understanding correct? And what about the other pins (other than DQ Pins)? They should be connected as is?

Sorry for such an elaborate question, since it is my first design, I am trying to be a bit careful.

Comment: This question might be better directed to Microchip support.